# Are there built-in "simplifications" with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Is there any built-in way to use Roslyn to perform the same compile-time transformations that the C# compiler does, e.g. for transforming iterators, initializers, lambdas, LINQ, etc. into basic C# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, no, there is no such thing exposed in Roslyn. But the compiler has to do these transformations somehow, so it's possible you will be able to do this by accessing some `internal` method.

Of course, you could use Roslyn to make these transformations yourself, but that's not what you're asking.

Comment: +1 darn, thanks. Seems like there's documentation for it (`LambdaRewriter`?) but the entire class is internal!

Comment: It also seems to be using stuff like `BoundNode` which is also internal. :(

Comment: You can use `internal` stuff using Reflection, it's just not very convenient.

Comment: Yup, but figuring out how to use them is the first hurdle.

Answer (score 5):

The Roslyn compiler API is designed to (in addition to translating source code to IL) let you build source code analysis and transformations tools.

However, lambdas and iterators do not have translations that can always be specified using source.  They are modeled using the internal bound node abstraction that includes additional compiler specific rules that can only be represented using IL.

It would be possible to translated LINQ to source in C#, since it is specified as a source code translation (whether the compiler actually does it that way or not.)  Yet, there is no compiler API that does this specifically. If there was, it would probably show up as a services layer API and not a compiler API.

Comment: I know you're right about iterators, exception handling is done in a way that isn't expressible as C#, but what do lambdas need that isn't representable as C#? (Edit: other than using names that aren't valid in C#, of course. Any name could be used.)

Comment: What makes iterators not expressible in C#? Aren't they just state normal machines?

Comment: @Mehrdad: John Skeet has a good writeup of how they are implemented at http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx. In particular, we will sometimes generate gotos that cross things that are normally disallowed in C#.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: Ahh, I see, I didn't realize some of the goto's are illegal. :-) Thanks!